Windows npm install not working Error: Cannot find module 'node'
I started using my windows machine after not using it for a month. I've made no changes.
When I try to run npm install I get the issues below:
I can't upgrade node 12 to something higher due to dependencies.

Uninstalling npm, nvm, node  Removing temp directories for each as
needed.
re-installing node from the wiki for 12, 20, and 22.
Installing only nvm and trying to install node using nvm only
Installing node and trying to switch to the correct one and use the
correct node.
Only installing node 12.
Doing code changes directly to the npm global cli.js file.

PS C:\Users\user\project\web> nvm use 12
Now using node v12.22.12 (64-bit)
PS C:\Users\user\project\web> node -v   
v20.18.0
PS C:\Users\user\project\web> npm install
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node'
# Alternate error:
Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'

Require stack:
- C:\.tools\.npm-global\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\.tools\.npm-global\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\.tools\.npm-global\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\.tools\\.npm-global\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\.tools\\.npm-global\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

I've reviewed:

NPM: npm-cli.js not found when running npm
NVM for Windows not working?

